# Airflow imports into tasks

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm wondering, if Airflow refreshes dags every X time,

How it is better (performance speaking) to import modules that will be used inside tasks:

A:

```
def _task_function(ti):
    import json
...
```

B:

```
import json
def _task_function(ti):
    ....
```

And then

```
with DAG('DAG_NAME',
         start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 27)
         ...) as dag:


    task_a = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_a",
        python_callable=_task_function,
    )
     ...
)
```

Comment: Here the topic is discussed as part of the best practice.  Especially for the large lib, you want to avoid top-level imports.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for!